# How to reload a page when navigating backward

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, reload

I have a navigation controller and some view controllers and I check NSUserDefaults to see if a certain parameter is set.This determines the options I have when I leave this first page and navigate further. In the case it is set I branch one way to a ViewController and continue with validated data, if it is not I branch another way to a ViewController and enter, validate, and set the information and update the NSUserDefaults data then I move backward on the navigation stack to the first page and I want it to recheck the NSUserDefaults and display the updated data, basically reload the page from scratch this time it will show validated data and let me continue.

I know the validation works because if rerun the App from Xcode it shows the validated data I just want to do it without rerunning the App by reloading the first ViewController completely.

It may be just a reload command but I am not sure where it would go.

Answer (score 0):

you can either use delegates and update your root vc when you make the changes or you can use notifications which can be generated when you make a change